# PHP and MYSQL database connection and table creation only once

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm developing a small application for my academic. i have a registration form and a log_in form. Here is what i want, i have a database configuration file which contains "**connection to server, creating database and creating table queries**" included in it. I've included this database file at the top of my registration form so that when the page is loaded the "**query should execute and create database and table ONLY ONCE**". But the problem is the query is successfully executing for the first time but when the registration page is loaded again, it prompt's an error "DATABASE ALREADY EXISTS". Please me.
I've attached the db.php code..

```
<?php
$dbhost  = 'localhost';
$dbuser  = 'root';
$dbpass  = '';
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$connect) {
    die('SERVER CONNECTION FAILED...\n: ' . mysql_error());
}
;
$sql    = 'CREATE DATABASE USERS';
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
if (!$retval) {
    die('DATABASE CREATION FAILED\n: ' . mysql_error());
}
;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE USERS( " . "Memberid int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        " . "Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        " . "Username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        " . "Password varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        " . "Email varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        " . "Activation varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
        " . "Status int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
        " . "PRIMARY KEY (`Memberid`)); ";
mysql_select_db('USERS');
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
if (!$retval) {
    die('COULD NOT CREATE TABLE\n: ' . mysql_error());
}
;
mysql_close($connect);
?>
<html>
    <body>
    //registration form code
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

query to create database only once if it doesn't exists

```
            CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;
```

query to create table only once if it doesn't exists

```
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to create database/table once only.

Change

```
CREATE DATABASE
```

To:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Same changes should be applied for the table creation statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
```

And for table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename;
```