# Undefined variable in php registration from

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Continuing from my previous post "[PHP and MYSQL database connection and table creation only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369364/php-and-mysql-database-connection-and-table-creation-only-once)", I created the registration form with the PHP code and server side validation. I’m getting some errors as stated below. 
i.e. all errors are occurring at the place where i try to print the errors in their respected html class “”. I've made the html "span class" text bold for easy recognition. If their is anything extra solutions for better performance of the form please let me know...

**List of errors:**

> Notice: Undefined variable:  error_name  in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php
>   Notice: Undefined variable:  error_username  in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php
>   Notice: Undefined variable:  error_password  in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php
>   Notice: Undefined variable:  error_password2  in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php
>   Notice: Undefined variable:  error_email  in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php

**Register.php**

```
<?php
include ‘database.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = " ";        //Declare a null variable to store error messages  

    //validation for fullname
    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
        $error_name = 'Enter Fullname...';
    } else {
        $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fullname'])); 
    }

    //validation for username
    if (empty($_POST['username'])){
        $error_username = 'Enter Username...';
    } else {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    }

    //validation for password
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $error_password = 'Please Enter Your Password...';
    } else {
        if (empty($_POST['password2'])) {
            $error_password2 = 'Re-enter Your Password...';
        } else {
            if(($_POST['password'])!=($_POST['password2'])){
                $error_password2 = 'Passwords Do not match...';
            } else {
                $confirm = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password2']));
            }
        }
    }

    //validation for e-mail
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error_email = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("//custom preg match characters", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
            //regular expression for email validation
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        } else {
            $error_email = 'Your E-mail Address is invalid '; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '
    {
        $query= "DB INSERT QUERY";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Failed to Register Your Account...!';
        } else {
            echo 'Account Registered Successfully...!';
        }
    }   
    mysqli_close($sql);//Close the DB Connection
} 
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="user_registration">
<p id="head">Create Account</p>

<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname"/>
**<span class="error" id="fullname"><?php echo $error_name; ?></span>**

<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
<span id="availability_status"></span>
**<span class="error" id="username"><?php echo $error_username; ?></span>**

<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> 
**<span class="error" id="password"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>**

<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"/>
**<span class="error" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"><?php echo $error_password2;?></span>**

<input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
**<span class="error" id="email"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>**

<p class="submit">
<button type="submit"id="submit" name="submit" value="Register”>Register</button>
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Please correct the quote at `include ‘database.php';`, it's blocking the rest of the code.

Comment: Curly quotes; beautiful yet *deadly*.

Comment: An empty string is not null ... just sayin.

Comment: Sidenote: Using MD5 for password storage, highly **not** recommended.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger, @ Fred -ii, @Y U NO WORK..thank you very much. Your answers solved many of my errors and helped me a lot..:)

Comment: You're welcome @CharanBalse Glad to see a solution was found, cheers. Do be careful when wanting to use quotes. Maybe you are using Windows Write/Word as a text editor or copied from the Web. That could happen and will throw an error when using those "beautiful, yet deadly" curly quotes ;-) Look into using [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt) or PHP 5.5 [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function for password storage.

Comment: @ Fred -ii, Thank U for ur precious solution, learnt a lot from those..:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is, you are setting the messages only if certain conditions are `true`. Thus, these variables are not found if those conditions aren't `true`. To resolve this, use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) when displaying the errors, e.g.

```
<?php echo isset($error_name)?$error_name:'' ; ?>
```

This means check if `$error_name` is set, if yes display it or display nothing.

Another thing (logically) is that your code is not actually checking for the errors. The `$error` remains an empty string and you are checking if it is empty which will always be true. You need to either store the errors as arrays or check if all the variables are empty.

## Additional:

> Can u tell me how to store the errors as arrays..plz

Try this:

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = array();        //<-- Declare array here 

    //validation for fullname
    if (empty($_POST['fullname'])) {
        $error['fullname'] = 'Enter Fullname...'; //<-- adding error into array
    } else {
        $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fullname'])); 
    }

    //validation for username
    if (empty($_POST['username'])){
        $error['username'] = 'Enter Username...'; //<-- here too and so on..
    } else {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    }

    //validation for password
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $error['password'] = 'Please Enter Your Password...';
    } else {
        if (empty($_POST['password2'])) {
            $error['password2'] = 'Re-enter Your Password...';
        } else {
            if(($_POST['password'])!=($_POST['password2'])){
                $error['password2'] = 'Passwords Do not match...';
            } else {
                $confirm = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password2']));
            }
        }
    }

    //validation for e-mail
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error['email'] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("//custom preg match characters", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
            //regular expression for email validation
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        } else {
            $error['email'] = 'Your E-mail Address is invalid '; 
        }
    }

    if (!empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '
    {
        $query= "DB INSERT QUERY";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Failed to Register Your Account...!';
        } else {
            echo 'Account Registered Successfully...!';
        }
    }   
} 
?>
```

Change your HTML to:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" id="user_registration">
<p id="head">Create Account</p>

<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname"/>
<!-- checking if error message is set -->
**<span class="error" id="fullname"><?php echo isset($error['fullname'])?$error['fullname']:''; ?></span>** 

<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
<span id="availability_status"></span>
**<span class="error" id="username"><?php echo isset($error['username'])?$error['username']:''; ?></span>**

<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/> 
**<span class="error" id="password"><?php echo isset($error['password'])?$error['password']:''; ?></span>**

<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"/>
**<span class="error" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"><?php echo isset($error['password2'])?$error['password2']:''; ?></span>**

<input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
**<span class="error" id="email"><?php echo isset($error['email'])?$error['email']:''; ?></span>**

<p class="submit">
<button type="submit"id="submit" name="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
</p>

</form>
```

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Can u tell me how to store the errors as arrays..plz

Comment: @CharanBalse I've updated the answer to show how you can store error messages as one array.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer solved many of my errors and helped me a lot.. But rite now i'm getting the following warnings...                              Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php...&...
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php

Comment: @CharanBalse Have you not written a `INSERT` query in place of `$query= "DB INSERT QUERY";`? Also `mysqli_close($sql);` you need to pass the connection object. Not sure if it's `$sql`. You need to check your `database.php` to find the connection object.

Comment: This is my insert query.. but still the warning occurs...$query= "INSERT INTO `users` ( `Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`) VALUES ( '$fullname', '$username', '$password2', '$email')";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50111/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-charan-balse)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fullname Notice: Undefined variable: username Notice: Undefined variable: confirm Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php...these errors are occuring in the following two lines..$query= "INSERT INTO users ( Name, Username, Password, Email) VALUES ( '$fullname', '$username', '$confirm', '$email')"; $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

Comment: @CharanBalse Updated the answer. `if (empty($error))` should be `if (!empty($error))` (the exclamation mark saying if no errors)

Answer (score 3):

First of all You need to fix the quote at `include ‘database.php';` to `include 'database.php';` never use curly quote due to this all your code is being blocked.

Next You need to initialize all variable to `null` or simply `""`

**OR**

You can check if the variable exist or not using `isset()` like if you want to print value of an variable `$val` then use this `if(isset($val)) echo $val;`

**UPDATE**

You can easily use an array to store errors:
simply use like

```
$error['name']='Enter Fullname...';
```

And to check if name error occurs use

```
if(isset($error['name'])){
//Its an error print error
}
```

Comment: There's also `value="Register”` for the bad quotes; don't forget that one. ;-)

Comment: Can i initialize all variables inside an array and then use it..? IF yes can u tell me how to do it..? plz..

Comment: Updated My answer check it out.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer solved many of my errors and helped me a lot.. But rite now i'm getting the following warnings... Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php

Comment: and YES my dB connection object is '$connect'. I tried using it like mysqli_close($connect); but still the warning occurs..

Comment: I cant say without looking on code I will suggest you to open an new question for it

Comment: My database code is shown in this link below..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369364/php-and-mysql-database-connection-and-table-creation-only-once

Comment: Seems you have made connection using mysql and using mysqli to close connection.
I will suggest you to convert your code into mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to define these variable on top of the page before using them in code something like this.

```
$error_name         = '';
$error_username     = '';
$error_password     = '';
$error_password2    = '';
$error_email        = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an else to your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

```
else { /* What if the user didn't click submit? Else is the answer */

$error_name="";
$error_username="";
$error_password="";
$error_password2="";  
$error_email="";

}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fullname 
Notice: Undefined variable: username 
Notice: Undefined variable: confirm 
Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php
Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\18+\register.php...these errors are occuring in the following two lines..$query= "INSERT INTO `users` ( `Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`) VALUES ( '$fullname', '$username', '$confirm', '$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);